# Share sessions between laravel subdomains

Tags: laravel

I have two laravel 7 projects, blog1 and blog2, I want when a user signs in using blog1 and when he/she visits blog2 is already logged in.

My valuables;

Blog1 (config.php)

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.blog.com'),
```

Blog1 (.env)

```
APP_KEY=base64:jiiuuiuriuriurj
APP_URL=http://blog.com
```

My valuables;

Blog2 (.env)

```
APP_KEY=base64:jiiuuiuriuriurj
APP_URL=http://blog2.blog.com
```

Comment: Are both blogs sharing the same sessions database table or are they pointing to different databases?

Comment: they are pointing to different databases sessions

Comment: They need to be pointing at the same sessions database in order to sync the sessions between both apps. If they are in Speer are DBs app1 has no way of knowing sessions in app2

Comment: I have to point the two projects to use same session table but nothing is happening